# Array.push() sempre empilhando o último item do forEach

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Estou trabalhando no desenvolvimento de uma table dinâmica e estou enfrentando problemas para criar as linhas dessa table conforme as colunas que eu tenho e a informação que recebo da API.

Considerando o seguinte código:

```js
let data = [];
let line = {};

const columns = [{
  name: "Code",
  dataIndex: "id"
}, {
  name: "Name",
  dataIndex: "name"
}];

const arrFromApi = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Marcus",
  age: "32"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "John",
  age: "30"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Emily",
  age: "25"
}];

arrFromApi.forEach(item => {
  columns.forEach(column => {
    line[column.dataIndex] = item[column.dataIndex];
  })
  data.push(line)
});

console.log(data)
```

Eu tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
[{id: 3, name: "Emily"}, {id: 3, name: "Emily"}, {id: 3, name: "Emily"}]
```

Porém, se eu substituir meu `data.push(line)` por `console.log(line)` é impresso no console corretamente cada um dos nomes da forma que preciso:

```
[{id: 1, name: "Marcus"}, {id: 2, name: "John"}, {id: 3, name: "Emily"}]
```

Alguém saberia dizer o que há de errado neste cenário? Pois entendo que se no console está imprimindo nessa sequência, logo o resultado final do meu array deveria ser o mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que acontece é que a cada iteração você está sobrescrevendo o `id` e `name` do objeto `line`.

O correto seria criar um novo objeto a cada iteração:

```js
let data = [];

const columns = [{
  name: "Code",
  dataIndex: "id"
}, {
  name: "Name",
  dataIndex: "name"
}];

const arrFromApi = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Marcus",
  age: "32"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "John",
  age: "30"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Emily",
  age: "25"
}];

arrFromApi.forEach(item => {
  let line = {}; // <--- Aqui
  columns.forEach(column => {
    line[column.dataIndex] = item[column.dataIndex];
  })
  data.push(line)
});

console.log(data)
```

O `console.log` só "funciona" porque ele mostra os dados que você acabou de setar no `line`. Mas como ele é o mesmo objeto em todas as iterações, no final você acaba com 3 cópias dele no array `data`. Ao criar um objeto novo a cada iteração, você elimina esse problema.

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma é convertendo o objeto `line` em string a cada iteração do `forEach` usando `JSON.stringify()` e parseando com `JSON.parse()`:

```
data.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(line)));
```

Com isso você não estará adicionando o mesmo objeto na array `data`, mas um objeto com valor independente do objeto `line`.

O que você está fazendo é basicamente isso:

```
data[line, line, line]
```

Onde a variável `line` é um objeto que ao final do `forEach` terá como valor o último objeto da array `arrFromApi`, ou seja `{"id":3,"name":"Emily"}`, conforme dito na resposta do hkotsubo.

Neste caso, você pode manter seu código como está, apenas alterando a linha do `push` como mencionado acima:

```js
let data = [];
let line = {};

const columns = [{
  name: "Code",
  dataIndex: "id"
}, {
  name: "Name",
  dataIndex: "name"
}];

const arrFromApi = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Marcus",
  age: "32"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "John",
  age: "30"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Emily",
  age: "25"
}];

arrFromApi.forEach(item => {
  columns.forEach(column => {
    line[column.dataIndex] = item[column.dataIndex];
  })
  data.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(line)));
});

console.log(data)
```